# Unexpected key found in preloadedState argument passed to createStore

Tags: javascript, redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

I am trying to write a redux integration test. My test successfully passes, however, I get the message:

> console.error node_modules/redux/lib/utils/warning.js:14
>       Unexpected key "word" found in preloadedState argument passed to createStore. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead:
>   "jotto", "router". Unexpected keys will be ignored.

It seems to me that my createStore and root reducer look fine. Is there something I need to change that is messing up this preloaded state? You can find the scripts below. Thanks!

**jottoRedux.test.js:**

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import {routerMiddleware} from 'connected-react-router';
import rootReducer from 'reducers/rootReducer';
import {initialState} from './jottoReducer';
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
const middleware = applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history), thunkMiddleware);

export const storeFactory = () =>
  createStore(rootReducer(createBrowserHistory()), {...initialState}, middleware);


export const setWord = (word) => ({
  type: 'SET_WORD',
  word,
});

describe('testing SET_WORD action', () => {
  let store;
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = storeFactory();
  });

  test('state is updated correctly for an unsuccessful guess', () => {
    store.dispatch(setWord('foo'));
    const expectedState = {
      ...initialState,
      word: 'foo',
    };
    const newState = store.getState().jotto;
    expect(newState).toEqual(expectedState);
  });
});
```

**jottoReducer.js:**

```
export const initialState = {
  word: null,
};

const jotto = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_WORD':
      return {
        ...state,
        word: action.word,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default jotto;
```

**rootReducer:**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {connectRouter} from 'connected-react-router';
import jotto from './jottoReducer';

export default (historyObject) => combineReducers({
  jotto,
  router: connectRouter(historyObject),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
export const storeFactory = () =>
  createStore(rootReducer(createBrowserHistory()), { jotto: initialState }, middleware);
```